# How to send a browser notification when a specific time occurs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm creating a to-do app with MEAN stack. Input will be to-do text and to-do time, which will be stored in database. This is my code to fetch client browser time and send notification with that time. But what I need is, notification should be send when the time stored in database occurs. How I can do that? Atleast how I can get the variable btime in server?

```
<script>
        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
        var time = new Date();
        var bhours = time.getHours();
        var bminutes = time.getMinutes();
        var btime = bhours + ':' + bminutes;
        var notification = new Notification(btime);
      });
</script>
```

Comment: make a http request to the server using angulars http service

Comment: How I can get the variable btime in server? or in js file where my controller is defined. I'm new to angular.

Comment: Do you mean how do I send the btime to the server? My previous comment answers that. You'll need an API on the server side to call to though

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var notify = function() {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
         //function
        })
        .error(function(data) {
           //function
        });
  }).catch((err) => {
    //function
  });
};
```